# VLookup across two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I've read many posts, but haven't quite found exactly the code that works (I'm new to VBA and unsure about proper syntax).  What I have and what I need is simple.  In one workbook, I have a list of names and email addresses (names in Column "A" and email addresses in Column "B").  In the second workbook, I have names in Column "A" (which come from the first workbook), but am missing some email addresses.  I need to perform a VLookup so that the missing email addresses get pulled into the second workbook.  The first workbook changes daily and feeds only the new names to the second workbook; I need to bring in the corresponding email addresses associated with the new names.  Sounds simple, but I can't get the macro to work.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Please share the code in your question.

Comment: I figured out the issue.  The macro works fine (but by all means pls review my code for any issues that you may see) but it can't see the file name that the VLookup is performed on because the file name changes every day (e.g., DailyFile 8-16-16; next day's file is called DailyFile 8-17-16, and so on).  I download the file daily from a vendor.  The easy fix is just re-name & save the file as "DailyFile" with no date, but the boss doesn't want us changing the file name.  Is there any way to make the macro see the file regardless of the date in the file name?  Here is my code:

Comment: Also need to know how to how to auto fill a variable range and make the macro see the file name that changes daily.  Here is my code:Sub addNewUsersEmail()
Call activateMasterWorkbook
Sheets(MasterUsersSheet).Activate
 
    Range("C10").Select
    If Range("C10").Value = "" Then
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],'[Daily_Report 8-15-16]Current Data'!R1C1:R5000C2,2,0)"
 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C10:C12"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C10:C12").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 
End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Use the macro recorder enter a Vlookup formula into a cell. Stop the macro recorder. Now you have the syntax for Vlookup in VBA. Loop through your data grid and execute the Vlookup when the target cell is empty.